# How can I update the username and password for my project

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a Visual Studio project with two forms

First to login

The second is to change the username and password

I have a problem when I want to update my username and

> (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in UPDATE statement.')

I tried but it didn't work

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class User

    Public DA As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Public DT As New DataTable
    'الأتصال بقاعدة البيانات  2007
    Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Abo Khallad\Desktop\Visual Studio VB.Net\Test VB.Net\Login User\bin\Debug\Notes.accdb"
    Dim Conn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    Public ds1 As New DataSet


    Sub Fill_DGV()
        'كود عرض قاعدةالبيانات بالداتا جريد فيو
        Dim dataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Login", connectionString)
        Dim dataSet As New DataSet()
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub FrmUser_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TxtNewUser.Focus()
        TxtNewUser.Enabled = False
        TxtNewPass.Enabled = False
        BtnOk.Enabled = False
        Fill_DGV()  'كود عرض قاعدةالبيانات بالداتا جريد فيو
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Clear()
        DA = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Login", Conn)
        DA.Fill(dt)

    End Sub

   Private Sub BtnOk_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnOk.Click
        ' كود زر التأكيد
        If TxtOldUser.Text = "" And TxtOldPass.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("من فضلك ادخل اسم المستخدم وكلمة المرور)", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxRtlReading + MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxRight + vbOKOnly, Title:="ملاحظة")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand("Update Login Set User = @User, Pass = @Pass Where User = @User", Conn)
        Dim User As String = TxtNewUser.Text
        Dim Pass As String = TxtNewPass.Text
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = User
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pass", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Pass
        Conn.Open()
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Conn.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Note: OleDb does not use named parameters.  It doesn't throw an error, but essentially, the parameters are all '?' and get supplied in the order they appear in the string.  So you are missing a parameter: the second `user`.  You aren't going to be able to update the user name with that query since if the user name is different, it won't find it in the table, or it's updating someone else's login.  That table needs a primary key that can't be changed.  The query you posted doesn't look like it would throw that syntax error.

Comment: You can use names for parameters but they are only for your own ease of reading. They are ignored by the system. That means that you should use a different name for each parameter. Even if they are to contain the same value, you have to add each one. The thing is, how could your `@User` parameters be considered to contain the same value? If you want to change the username, you need to provide the new `User` value to set and the old `User` value for the `WHERE` clause. Even if a single parameter could be used that way, it still wouldn't work except to change the password only.